# Sublime Text 2 with LateXTools - strange autocompletion behavior

Tags: sublimetext2

I am taking first steps writing LateX documents using Sublime Text 2 and the Latextools package. There is some strange autocompletion behavior that I cannot figure out. I would like to write the word "reform", but after typing only the first three letters, Sublime immediately changes them to \ref{. This happens without me pressing enter, tab, or any other key. How do I turn this off, without turning off all of autocompletion?

For the record, I am using Windows 7. There is nothing unusual in my user settings, as far as I can tell:

```
{
"color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Solarized (Light).tmTheme",
"auto_complete_selector": "source, text",
"ignored_packages":
[
    "Vintage"
]
}
```

As for the Latextools settings,I have not changed those since installing the package.

Edit: I just discovered that the odd behavior disappears when I remove the word "text" from the line

```
"auto_complete_selector": "source, text",
```

from my settings. However, I have become quite fond of the drop-down menu that appears when I type a word that appears earlier in my document, and would not like to go without this option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to the end of your `Preferences -> Settings - User` file:

```
"auto_complete_commit_on_tab": true
```

(and make sure to add a comma after the `]` of the `ignored_packages` setting as you're continuing the list). This will make sure that autocomplete only occurs after you hit tab. I could duplicate your issue when I typed `ref` immediately followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd>, so hopefully this will solve the problem. Good luck!

**EDIT**

In `Packages/LaTeXTools/`, rename `latex_ref_completions.py` to `latex_ref_completions.py.bak`, then delete `latex_ref_completions.pyc` and restart Sublime. You may lose a little functionality, but you won't have this incredibly annoying behavior!

I don't have the time to completely debug it, but it looks like the autocomplete mechanism is a bit too broad, and is resulting in the behavior you're seeing. I'd head over to the Github repository and open an [issue](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues), after searching to see if there isn't one open already.

Comment: Unfortunately, that hasn't solved the problem, even after restarting Sublime. Any other ideas?

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick, and to the extent that I've lost functionality, well, I haven't noticed it yet.